# Related to one of the twin prime conjectures (In between squares)

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

This question is inspired by an answer that I have received for another question [[see here]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369516/comparing-sets-of-twin-primes-with-other-sets-why-is-there-a-max-and-min-value):

One of the twin prime conjectures states that Between the squares of two consecutive odd numbers $[2n+1]^2$ and $[2(n+1)+1]^2$ there is always at least one pair of twin primes .

In my attempts to compare between sets of twin pairs with other sets, I have made a comparison with a
consecutive list of numbers as follow 1, 1+2=3 , 1+2+3=6 ,  1+2+3+4=10 ,  1+2+3+4+5=15 up till $18413346$ (Sorry for the limit but, My script keeps crashing after that). Let's call the numbers in this set $B$.

If $B < 188806$: There are 35 consecutive numbers that have no twin primes between them.

If $B > 188805$: So far all of the consecutive numbers have twin primes between them.

Is it a known conjecture (If a conjecture at all), and are there any similar conjectures between twin primes and other consecutive sets (especially ones that grow slower)?

[See the results here](http://numbersprime.com/crawlt.php)

In a related effort,I have also made a small heuristic showing that there are probably never more than 3 consecutive twin pairs when $B$ being the first of the pair and $B > 43$ and between the range of $B - 15$ to $B + 17$. Also probably never more than 2 consecutive pairs when $B > 13$ and between $B - 7$ to $B + 9$ [See Here](http://numbersprime.com/crawltt.php)? Any knowledge about it will be appreciated  too.

Comment: I think the standard conjecture would be that for any positive $k$ there's always a pair of twin primes between $m$ and $m+k\sqrt m$, provided $m$ is large enough (as a function of $k$). The triangular numbers would correspond to $k=\sqrt2$.

Comment: Yes I think you are right.